# How to avoid implicit any when iterating over object keys in Typescript

Tags: typescript, index-signature

The following code:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: string;
  qux: string;
  baz: number;
}

const foo: Foo = {
  bar: '42',
  qux: 'baz',
  baz: 5
};

const keysToIterateOver = [ 'bar', 'qux' ];

keysToIterateOver.forEach(key => foo[key] = 'newStringValue');
```

gives TypeScript compile error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Foo' has no index signature
```

How can I tell the compiler that I am only iterating over keys that have a string value and can safely reassign their values?

Comment: Note that the rule is not prohibiting the use of any. It's prohibiting the use of **implicit** any. Just make it **explicit** that the type is any, and the error disappears: `(foo as any)[key] = 'newStringValue'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by specifying the type of `keysToIterateOver`:

```
const keysToIterateOver: (keyof Foo)[] = [ 'bar', 'qux' ];
```

Otherwise the inferred type is `string[]`, hence the error

Comment: OK, this suppresses the error. But when I do: const keysToIterateOver: (keyof Foo)[] = [ 'bar', 'qux', 'baz' ] the compiler doesn't give any error even though I'm now essentially trying to assign a string value to foo.baz

Comment: Sorry, missed the _have a string value_ part

Comment: Well, essentially I just want to tell the compiler that I know what I'm doing and your answer solves that. I'm just surprised that the compiler doesn't warn if I iterate over wrong keys.

Comment: `string|number` is inferred, that's why string is allowed. If you'll try to do something like `foo[key] = false` - it will result in error

Answer (score 0):

Compiler can not detect dynamic property's type and considers the property to have `any` type. As a workaround you can write your interface with indexer. This will tell to the compiler that any dynamic accessed property with `[]` indexer contains `string` or `number` and the `foo[key] = 'newStringValue'` assignment is correct.

```
interface Foo {
    [prop: string]: string | number,
    bar: string;
    qux: string;
    baz: number;
}
```

Another variant is to remove the `"noImplicitAny": true,` from *tsconfig.json* file, but it is not the best one.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that you can use a "string | number" notation in interfaces

Comment: This radically changes the nature of the Foo interface. Now it's saying that it can contain any property, of type string or number. That's not desired.

Comment: @JBNizet You are right. The below answer is more correct.